# How to judge whether the sample in a new data set belongs to original data set in PyTorch?

Tags: dataset, pytorch, shuffle

I am new to PyTorch. Now, I have two data sets named A and B (eg: MNIST). I want to mix A and B together to form a new data set. And I want to shuffle this new data set. During the period of training, I need to determine whether the sample in batch is belongs to A. How can I do this?

The two problems are as follows:
1)How can I mix two datasets and shuffle it?
2)How can I determine whether the sample in new data set is belongs to original data set A?

Answer (score 0):

By defining custom dataset and some flag labels you can achieve that.
Here's sample code:

```
import torch
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset 

class to_dataset(Dataset):

    def __init__(self , data_A, data_B):
        self.lena   = data_A.shape[0]
        self.len    = data_A.shape[0] + data_B.shape[0]
        self.A      = torch.from_numpy(data_A).float()
        self.B      = torch.from_numpy(data_B).float()
     
    # returns dataset A data with flag label 0
    # dataset B data with flag label 1
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index < self.lena:            
            return self.A[index], 0
        retutn self.B[index-self.lena], 1

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len

   
#reading sample numpy dataset
data_a  = np.load(pathofA)
data_b  = np.load(pathofB)
 
# loading custom dataset
dataset = to_dataset(data_a, data_b)

#loading dataloader with training data
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset, batch_size=bsize, shuffle=True)

#sample train loop
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for data, label in train_loader:
        for d,l in zip(data, label):  
            if l == 0:
                print('from A')
            else:
                print('from B')
```

Comment: for further detail to this comment, Solve it as a multilabel approach in which every sample has two labels(one belongs to the classes and other one to the dataset A and write a custom dataloader for it.